# Dictionary python trouble

Tags: python

Okay if I have a filed stored as sys.argv[1] and this file is just 3 lines, each line containing the name of a .txt file which then contains a list of cat breeds. I want to open sys.argv[1] and then systematically open each text file associated with each line of sys.argv[1]. For each text file I want to create a dictionary counting how many times each breed was listed. Finally I want to have a dictionary that contains all of these individual dictionaries with the key for each individual dictionary being its name as listed in the sys.argv[1] file. Here is what I tried:

```
f = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
all_cats = {}
for line in f:
    w = open(line, 'r')
    cat_count = {}
    for line in w:
        line = line.lower()
        for mark in string.punctuation:
            if mark in line:
                line = line.replace(mark, '')
        line = line.split()
        for cat in line:
            if word not in cat_count:
                cat_count[cat] = 1
            else:
                cat_count[cat] += 1
        all_cats[line] = cat_count
    w.close() 
f.close()
```

my expected out put would be

```
{'catdictionary#1.txt' : {'long hair': 0, 'short hair' : 1} 'cat dictionary#2.txt' : {'long hair' : 1, 'short hair' : 0}}
```

Comment: I would change `w = open(line, 'r')` to `w = open(line.rstrip(), 'r')`.

Comment: Post a _minimal_ working example, or people will keep down-voting.

Comment: I can't make an example that works is the problem

Comment: I'm getting the error     all_cats[line.rstrip()] = cat_count
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rstrip' and if i change it to all_cats[line] = cat_count I get all_cats[line] = cat_count
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: What is `string.punctuation`?

Comment: Because you made `line` a list when you did `line = line.split()`. So then `all_cats[line] = cat_count` is trying to pass an entire list as dict key, which doesn't make sense, since you want `all_cats` keyed on breed. But you probably want to just iterate over `line` and increment `all_cats` directly like you do with `cat_count`, and do away with the need for `cat_count`. (In any case, Python's `collections.Counter / defaultdict` are seriously useful for this.)

Comment: @Rohit he's lacking imports on the top of his code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try something like this. It uses the specialized Counter class for each of the "cat files".  For my sample data I have drink recipes :)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re, sys
from collections import Counter


file_count = dict()
filenames = [ name.strip() for name in open(sys.argv[1]) ]

for name in filenames:
    for line in open(name):
        cat_count = Counter()
        for cat in re.sub('[^a-zA-Z ]+', '', line.rstrip()).split():
            cat_count[cat] += 1
        file_count[name] = cat_count

print file_count
```

file: cats.txt

```
cat1.txt
cat2.txt
```

file: cat1.txt

```
whiskey
sugar syrup
```

file: cat2.txt

```
whiskey
```

Sample run:

```
./countcats.py cats.txt
{'cat1.txt': Counter({'syrup': 1, 'sugar': 1}), 'cat2.txt': Counter({'whiskey': 1})}
```